# Creating XOR across several IN clauses within the WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create an exclusive or statement within an in clause. For example

```
WHERE ACCOUNT IN (1,2,3) XOR ACCOUNT IN (3,4) XOR ACCOUNT IN (5,6)
```

The only reference materials I can find do not facilitate using an IN clause. TIA.

**Edit - Clarification :**

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE 
(
    CONTRACT    VARCHAR2(1),
    ID_NUMBER   NUMBER,
    ACCOUNT     NUMBER, 
    AMOUNT_1    NUMBER, 
    AMOUNT_2    NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('A', 1, 100, 5, NULL);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('A', 2, 101, NULL, 5);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('A', 3, 200, 2, NULL);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('B', 4, 100, 7, NULL);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('B', 5, 100, 3, NULL);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('B', 6, 101, NULL, 10);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('B', 7, 200, 2, NULL);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('C', 8, 200, 10, NULL);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('C', 9, 200, 5, NULL);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('C', 10, 201, NULL, 15);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('C', 11, 300, 6, NULL);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('C', 12, 301, NULL, 6);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('D', 13, 100, NULL, -5);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('D', 14, 100, NULL, 5);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('D', 15, 300, 7, 3);

INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, AMOUNT_1, AMOUNT_2)
VALUES ('D', 16, 200, NULL, 4);
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
    A.CONTRACT, 
    COUNT(NVL(ID_NUMBER,1)) AS ID_NUMBER_COUNT,
    LISTAGG(ID_NUMBER, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY CONTRACT) AS ID_NUMBERS,
    SUM(NVL(AMOUNT_1,0)) AS AMOUNT_1_SUM,                                   
    SUM(NVL(AMOUNT_2,0)) AS AMOUNT_2_SUM                                    
    FROM EXAMPLE A
    WHERE 1=1
        AND NOT (NVL(AMOUNT_1,0) = NVL(AMOUNT_2,0)) 
    GROUP BY CUBE(CONTRACT,ACCOUNT)
) A
WHERE 1=1
    AND NVL(A.AMOUNT_1_SUM,0) = NVL(A.AMOUNT_2_SUM,0)
    AND CONTRACT IS NOT NULL
```

The CUBE function may seem like overkill for this example, but my actual table has several more descriptor columns that necessitates searching across the combinations.

If you run the query on the above table, without any IN clause to limit the accounts, you will not receive the true population of records that are offsets (should clarify that they only sum to zero if they are in the same column, other wise an offset will occur across both columns where the aggregated amounts are equal).

The true population of records that I am aiming to capture is:

-On contract A, ID Numbers 1 and 2

-On contract B, ID Number 4,5, and 6

-On contract C, all ID Numbers

-On contract D, all ID Numbers

The query as it stands currently can capture all ID numbers across contracts C and D, however there are records in contracts A and B that will not come back as a valid result unless the accounts are limited.

-Limiting account to IN (100,101) will yield the ID numbers from A and B that I aim to capture. The caveat is that there are ~20 combinations of accounts in my full population that must be searched.

-There will never be an offset that occurs between two different contracts. I handle this in the query on the full population by using GROUPING_ID, then just excluding anywhere the Contract field is blank.

-As a last resort, I can use a UNION statement, but would like to do without using one.

-The only other thing I can currently think to do is to define the sets of accounts somewhere before I run the query, then just run a FOR loop for each set.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `A XOR B` is `( A AND NOT B ) OR ( B AND NOT A )` which would make your query something like this:

```
WHERE ( ACCOUNT IN (1,2,3) AND ACCOUNT NOT IN (3,4,5,6) )
OR    ( ACCOUNT IN (3,4)   AND ACCOUNT NOT IN (1,2,3,5,6) )
OR    ( ACCOUNT IN (5,6)   AND ACCOUNT NOT IN (1,2,3,3,4) )
```

However, the question does not really make sense as `ACCOUNT` cannot have multiple values so (apart from `3` which appears in multiple sets) you appear to be testing for the equivalent of `A XOR NOT A` which will always be true (when `ACCOUNT <> 3`).

Given this, the logic above will simplify to:

```
WHERE ACCOUNT IN (1,2,4,5,6)
```

**Edit - Following the clarification of the question**:

**Oracle Setup**:

I renamed the `Amount_1` and `Amount_2` columns to `Credit` and `Debit`

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE( CONTRACT, ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, CREDIT, DEBIT ) AS
SELECT 'A',  1, 100, 5,  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',  2, 101, NULL,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',  3, 200, 2,  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  4, 100, 7,  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  5, 100, 3,  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  6, 101, NULL, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  7, 200, 2,  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',  8, 200, 10, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',  9, 200, 5,  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 10, 201, NULL, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 11, 300, 6,  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 12, 301, NULL,  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 13, 100, NULL, -5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 14, 100, NULL, 5  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 15, 300, 7, 3     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 16, 200, NULL, 4  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 17, 100, 3, NULL  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 18, 200, NULL, 4  FROM DUAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TransactionObj AS OBJECT(
  ID_NUMBER INT,
  ACCOUNT   INT,
  VALUE     INT
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TransactionTable AS TABLE OF TransactionObj;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getMaxZeroSum(
  Transactions TransactionTable
) RETURN TransactionTable
AS
  zeroSumTransactions TransactionTable := Transactiontable();
  bitCount    INT;
  valueSum    INT;
  maxBitCount INT := 0;
  valueMax    INT := 0;
BEGIN
  IF Transactions IS NULL OR Transactions IS EMPTY THEN
    RETURN zeroSumTransactions;
  END IF;
  FOR i IN 1 .. POWER( 2, Transactions.COUNT ) - 1 LOOP
    bitCount := 0;
    valueSum := 0;
    FOR j IN 1 .. Transactions.COUNT LOOP
      IF BITAND( i, POWER( 2, j - 1 ) ) > 0 THEN
        valueSum := valueSum + Transactions(j).VALUE;
        bitCount := bitCount + 1;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF valueSum = 0 AND bitCount > maxBitCount THEN
      maxBitCount := bitCount;
      valueMax    := i;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  IF maxBitCount > 0 THEN
    zeroSumTransactions.EXTEND( maxBitCount );
    bitCount := 0;
    FOR j IN 1 .. Transactions.COUNT LOOP
      IF BITAND( valueMax, POWER( 2, j - 1 ) ) > 0 THEN
        bitCount := bitCount + 1;
        zeroSumTransactions(bitCount) := transactions(j);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  RETURN zeroSumTransactions;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT  zs.Contract,
        LISTAGG( t.ID_NUMBER, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ID_NUMBER ) AS ids,
        LISTAGG( t.ACCOUNT, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ID_NUMBER ) AS accounts
FROM    (
          SELECT CONTRACT,
                 getMaxZeroSum( CAST( COLLECT( TransactionObj( ID_NUMBER, ACCOUNT, NVL( CREDIT, 0 ) - NVL( DEBIT, 0 ) ) ) AS TransactionTable ) ) AS Transactions
          FROM   EXAMPLE
          WHERE  NVL( CREDIT, 0 ) <> NVL( DEBIT, 0 )
          GROUP BY CONTRACT
        ) zs,
        TABLE( zs.Transactions ) (+) t
GROUP BY Contract;
```

**Output**:

```
CONTRACT IDS            ACCOUNTS
-------- -------------- --------------------
A        1,2            100,101             
B        4,5,6          100,100,101         
C        8,9,10,11,12   200,200,201,300,301 
D        13,14,15,16    100,100,300,200
E        NULL           NULL
```

The `getMaxZeroSum` function could almost certainly be improved to consider the transactions in order of least number of items excluded through to all-but-two excluded and then to return as soon as it finds a zero sum (however, I went for having an easy to write function as a demonstration of how it could be done over a performant one). But however you write it I can't see a way that isn't `O(n(2^n))` where `n` is the number of transactions for a given contract.

Comment: I should clarify - sorry. I am looking for balances across multiple different accounts that offset each other (sum to zero). I need to limit the sets of accounts that I am looking for offsets across because an offset may exist between accounts 1 and 2, but when account 3 is added it no longer sums to zero. I have a known set of accounts that offsets may exist between and these are what need to be in my where clause.

Comment: @keyoung1 That is not what you have asked in the question - I suggest you clarify your question and give a minimal working example with an example table (please include the DDL and DML statements), your expected results and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @keyoung1 Your problem description bears strong resemblance to the subset sum problem which is computationally hard (unless the account balances can be constrained) - expect the need to apply a suitable heuristics for viable performance.

Comment: @MT0 I posted the DDL/DML to hopefully shed more light on what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you.

Comment: @keyoung1 Updated but its not simple or particularly fast for large numbers of transactions per account.